# Using stored procedure to insert data from selection

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to insert data into another table using stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE T.countnum
AS
   Insert into T1 values(select count(*) from T.countTable)
```

But it isn't working I saw several example but not with selection. Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use db;
CREATE PROCEDURE T.countnum
AS
Insert into T1 ([column_name])
select count(*) 
from T.countTable
go
```

or

```
use db;
CREATE PROCEDURE T.countnum
AS

declare @counting int

select @counting = count(*) 
from T.countTable

Insert into T1 ([column_name]) values (@counting)

go
```

<strike>And you should specify the column to count like `select count(id) from T.countTable`</strike>

Comment: There's no reason not to use `COUNT(*)` if you're wanting just to count the total rows in a set.

Comment: At the end is the same if the column "id" as "PK" is not null. But yes you're right it's more understandable with count(*) != count(id) if "id" has null values.

Answer (score 1):

```
use db;
CREATE PROCEDURE T.countnum
AS
Insert into T1 values((select count(*) from T.countTable))
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Insert into T1(CountColumn) 
select count(*) from T.countTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable  
(  
    Column1,  
    Column2  
)  
EXEC [dbo].[yourStoredProcName]
```